# Understanding a Specific Detail in the KMP Pattern Matching Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, computer-science, string-matching

I have a question about the KMP pattern matching algorithm. Below is a code snippet for calculating the `next` array:

```
int GetNext(char ch[], int length, int next[]) {
    next[1] = 0;
    int i = 1, j = 0;
    while (i < length) {
        if (j == 0 || ch[i] == ch[j])
            next[++i] = ++j;
        else
            j = next[j];
    }
}
```

I understand the principle of this code as follows: Let's assume we want to determine **`next[j+1]`**, and we already know **`next[1], next[2],...next[j]`**. If **`next[j] = p`**, this means that the longest common prefix and suffix before the **`jth`** character of the string has a length of **`p-1`**. If the **`jth`** character of the string is equal to its **`pth`** character, then **`next[j+1] = p+1`**. Otherwise, we need to consider **`next[p]`**, and if **`next[p] = k`**, we compare the **`jth`** character of the string with its **`kth`** character.

My question is, why don't we compare the **`jth`** character of the string with its **`(p-1)th`** character? How can we be sure that comparing the **`jth`** character of the string with its **`pth`** character is definitely not the correct answer? For instance, consider the following string (where numbers in S1 are indices):

S1S2S3 S4S5S6 S7S8S9 S10 S11

Using the algorithm above to compute **`next[11]`**, we can determine that **`S1S2S3S4`** and **`S7S8S9S10`** are the longest common prefix and suffix for **`S11`**. My question is, how can we be certain of this? How can we be sure that **`S1S2S3S4S5`** and **`S6S7S8S9S10`** are not the longest common prefix and suffix for **`S11`**?

I want to understand the details of this algorithm; this question has been bothering me for a while

Answer (score 0):

The goal of the algorithm is for each position of the string, determine the length of the longest prefix that is also a suffix of the string ending at that position.

Let's write, for sanity, `IsPrefix(a, b)` if the first `a` characters of the string match the suffix of length `a` ending at position `b`.  We are trying to calculate the maximum value of `a` for each position `b`. `IsPrefix(0, b)` be trivially true.

First realize that if `IsPrefix(a + 1, b + 1)`, then `IsPrefix(a, b)`.  You are just matching one fewer character.  So we can find `next[b + 1]` by looking at all the values of `a` largest to smallest, such that both `IsPrefix(a, b)` and taking the first we find such that `ch[a] == ch[b + 1]`.

Next realize that since `next[b]` is the largest value such that `IsPrefix(next[b], b)`, if `next[b] > 0`, then `next[next[b]]` is the second largest value.  I think this is the part you're missing.  There can't be a value `next[next[b]] < q < next[b]` such that `IsPrefix(q, b)`.  If those `q` characters match the suffix ending at `b`, then they also match the suffix ending at `next[b]` and we'd have `next[next[b]] = q`.